# Get JSON response on form submit to display response data on success page

Tags: javascript, json, forms, post, get

I have a form that will POST to an api as JSON response on submit.

When the form is submitted successfully, it will go to a new page (success page). I want to display one of the response data from the form (email) on the success page.

The form POST method is working and I can see the JSON in the response header.

This is my working form submit JSON response function:

```
    <script>
        async function postFormDataAsJson({ url, formData }) {
            const plainFormData = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());

            const formDataJsonString = JSON.stringify(plainFormData);
            const fetchOptions = {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                    Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                },
                body: formDataJsonString,
            };

            const response = await fetch(url, fetchOptions);

            if (!response.ok) {
                const errorMessage = await response.text();
                throw new Error(errorMessage);
            }

            return response.json();
        }
    

        async function handleFormSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            const form = event.currentTarget;
            const url = form.action;

            try {
                const formData = new FormData(form);
                const responseData = await postFormDataAsJson({ url, formData });

                console.log({ responseData });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }

        const testform = document.getElementById(‘testform');
        testform.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmit);

    </script>
```

Here is the HTML for the submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Finish" class="btn-filled finish-btn" onclick="location='confirmation-success.html'">
```

How do I get the response out from JSON and use it in the success page? I have the success page and since it is a different page I figure that a method like appending the response to the URL might be an approach. But I've been through Google to find the right solution and no luck..

Comment: So where in this code is the part that actually makes it go to your success page?

Comment: Oh ya forgot about that. Added it in

Comment: Are we talking about an external API here, or a request to your own backend?

Comment: It is a request to my own backend.

Comment: Then it would probably make the most sense to store the data into a session, when this request is processed, so that you can access it from there on the success page. (Which seems to be a static HTML document in this case though? That would need to be made “dynamic” in some way to begin with, if you don’t want to handle the whole thing purely client-side.) Another option would be to not use AJAX in the first place, but submit the form to the processing script directly, and let that output the success page in response.

Comment: I see. So let's say if I took the approach to use localStorage (which works), when submit button is clicked, the user will be instantly be brought to the success page. In this case of instantly jumping out of the form page, and since the POST submit request usually took a few seconds to get 200 response code, will it cause the form to stop submitting?

Comment: If you want to submit the form data via AJAX, then you need to wait for that to finish, before you navigate to a different page - otherwise, the browser will cancel the still running background request.